# URL Rewrite in WebLogic 11g

Tags: weblogic, rewrite

I have a client running a WebLogic 11g install on a Windows Server machine who wishes to implement Apache-style mod_rewrite-like functionality to translate requests for easyurl.com to super.complicated.com/with/this/junk?here=and_more. I have scoured the Internet for advice, but all I can find are other people who are asking the same question and not getting any answer. Assuming that installing 3rd-party apps is not an option, how do I implement this in WebLogic?

To clarify, WebLogic is not running with Apache (or else I'd just use mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 1):

I had to look into the exact same thing for WebLogic to no avail. There is no URL Rewrite feature in weblogic (or some sort of workaround). The only way to do it is to add code e.g. a java filter to do it.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using Apache HTTPD with the [Apache HTTP Server Plug-In](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/plugins/apache.html) in front of WebLogic, then it should be possible to use `mod_rewrite` before to send request to WebLogic.
- If not, then you could use Tuckey's [Url Rewrite Filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (a Java Filter) that allows to rewrite URLs in a `mod_rewrite` like manner at the application server level.

Comment: I saw the filter, but I was trying to avoid third-party solutions (even though it's just a filter add-on to the WebLogic engine, it still needs to be managed and tracked by my client, and the less of that that needs to be done, the better). My problem ended up being simple enough that I used an http redirect, but unfortunately the question itself remains unresolved.

Comment: @wilsona The filter is not an addon to WebLogic, the Servlet Filter is part of the application, it's managed by the people developing/packaging/providing the application.

Comment: Agreed, you should always reverse proxy your Java app-servers with a real web server.